# How to get error/notification integer arithmetic overflow in Java?

Tags: java, math, netbeans, overflow

Let's have a simple code as below

```
public class Sandbox {

    public static void run(String[] args) {
        int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int j = i+1;
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(j);
    }
}
```

This will print output

> 2147483647
>
> -2147483648

Value at j is overlowed without any notice to me when the code is executed.

I use Netbeans IDE to run this code.

Is it possible to configure the system to notify us when such arithmetic overflow occurs?

Comment: You have to use if-else for this, to check for overflow manually.. Also,you have to create your own exeption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the last sentence in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2) (Chapter 15.18.2. Additive Operators (+ and -) for Numeric Types) :

> Despite the fact that overflow, underflow, or loss of information may occur, evaluation of a numeric additive operator never throws a runtime exception.

For a lengthy article on this problem and the presentation of a tool for workaround see the article [Signalling Integer Overflows in Java](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/signalling-integer-overflows-in-java/210500001?pgno=1).

Answer (score 0):

In the [Math API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) since Java 8, you can use:

```
Math.addExact(i, 1);
```

It will throw an `ArithmeticException` if the result overflows an `int`.